# How to pass multiple params to Saxon ExtensionFunction?

Tags: java, saxon

How can I pass multiple fields into a `Saxon-HE` `ExtensionFunction`?

The extension usually requires an array of arguments:

```
new ExtensionFunction {

    @Override
    public XdmValue call(XdmValue[] arguments) {

    }
}
```

Question: how can I create that array, if I want to call that function from xslt template, like (pseudocode):

```
<xsl:value-of select="..., ext:myfunc(//Sergment/First, //Segment/Second, $somevar) />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XPath call supplies 4 arguments, then your ExtensionFunction gets called with a (java) array containing 4 XdmValue objects, one for each argument.

Comment: Ok but what if I just want to provide xpath calls that each provide only one parameter. Thus having multiple arguments as in my question, whereas one arg could also be eg a variable defined before? Would I have to create an array of them first inside the xslt? If yes, how?

Comment: No, you don't have to create an array. Saxon does that for you.